# Xamarin AppCompat themes doesn't work in designer

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, android-appcompat

I just installed the **Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat** package from nuget, and created a style inheriting from `Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar` but if I open a layout in the designer it doesn't seem to take the style, it looks like this:

[image]

This is my theme defined in styles.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<resources>
    <style name="JackTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar"> 
    </style>
</resources>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding "@style/" ?

parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar"

Comment: Yes, it is the same, I think it's a problem with Xamarin Designer, it doesn't handle custom styles nor custom controls